# pandas: How to append the bin values back to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to Pandas and I have a dataframe like below

```
id    values   
 1       2.1
 2       0.8  
 3       1.0
 4       3.2
```

And I want to separate the columns "values" into different bins, like bin =2 and add a column "counts" which represents how many rows fall inside the bin, such as:

```
id     values   counts
 1        2.1       2 (since 2.1 and 3.2 both belong to the bin 2-4)
 2        0.8       2 
 3        1.0       2
 4        3.2       2
```

I know value_counts function can calculate the frequency, but I dont know how to append them back to the original dataframe.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `bins=2` is not the same assigning specific `bins`, e.g. `pd.cut(df['values'], bins=2)` vs `pd.cut(df['values'], bins=[0, 2, 4])`, e.g. the `bins` for the above data with `bins=2` is about `[ 0.8,  2.0,  3.2 ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `numpy`s `searchsorted` to define bins and `bincount` to count them.
*This should be very fast.*

```
#         This defines the bin edges
#        [1, 2, 3] would have created
#               different bins
#                    v
b = np.searchsorted([2], df['values'].values)
df.assign(counts=np.bincount(b)[b])

   id  values  counts
0   1     2.1       2
1   2     0.8       2
2   3     1.0       2
3   4     3.2       2
```

---

- `np.searchsorted` identifies where in the first array every element of the second array needs to be placed in order to maintain sortedness.

  - That means:
  - `2.1` needs to go after the `2` which is a position of `1`.
  - `0.8` needs to go before the `2` which is a position of `0`.
  - `1.0` needs to go before the `2` which is a position of `0`.
  - `3.2` needs to go after the `2` which is a position of `1`.
- `np.bincount` conveniently counts the frequency of integral bins... like the ones we just created.
- By slicing the counted bins by the occurrence of the bins, we get a `transform` like `count`

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, I'd really appreciate knowing why so that I could address any concerns.  Thank you.

Comment: offering up a numpy based solution that is somewhat esoteric and does not generalize across dtypes is not helpful; this is in fact why groupby exists

Comment: @Jeff I regret that you feel that way.  I'll offer up two points.  One, `searchsorted` is a `pandas` function as well and generalizes to the same degree as `pd.cut` given the circumstances of the the problem presented. Two, It is my opinion that providing a variety of ways to solve a problem is helpful. It acts to shine a light on the wide tapestry of solutions. It is these types of answers that help me learn. I'll leave the answer here and as is just incase others might share my opinion.

Comment: sure a variety of answers is nice, but as always in python there should be a canonical way of doing a task; especially for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

Let' use `pd.cut` and `groupby`:

For two bins:

```
df.assign(counts=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['values'], bins=2))['values'].transform('count'))
```

Or if you want your bin size = 2:

```
df.assign(counts=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['values'], bins=[0,2,4]))['values'].transform('count'))
```

Output:

```
   id  values  counts
0   1     2.1     2.0
1   2     0.8     2.0
2   3     1.0     2.0
3   4     3.2     2.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Both answers work for me but I can accept one of them

Comment: PiRSquare's answer is faster most likely.